# Php Mysql update statement not working (Syntax is correct)

Tags: php, mysql

I am not sure why my database is not being updated. The code runs and the success message is displayed but database remains the same. I have checked my syntax numerous times and have added mysql_error but I am not sure whats wrong.

```
if (!empty($username) && !empty($extension) && !empty($location)) {
                            $q2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `intranet`.`mmg_locations` WHERE `id`='{$location}' ") or die (mysql_error()) ;
                            $r2 = mysql_fetch_assoc();
                            $q = mysql_query("UPDATE `intranet`.`mmg_cpd_users` SET `name` = '{$username}', `extension` = '{$extension}', `location`='{$location}' 
                                            WHERE `id` = '{$id}' ") or die (mysql_error());


                           if ($q) {
                            echo '<p style="color: green;">The user '.$username.' has been successfully updated.</p>';
                            }
}
```

Comment: Where does `$id` come from? Do you perhaps mean to get that value from the `$r2` array?

Comment: i declared the value of id beforehand . The value of $id comes from another query. I echoed out the value of $id and its fine. the problem is not with the variables

Comment: Well, if the variables are correct and the syntax is correct, then there is no problem. Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Print $q in the browser before executing. Copy the whole UPDATE statement from browser and directly execute in phpmyadmin query browser

```
 $q = "UPDATE `intranet`.`mmg_cpd_users` 
       SET `name` = '{$username}', 
       `extension` = '{$extension}', 
       `location`='{$location}'
        WHERE `id` = '{$id}' ";

    echo $q;
    die();
    if ($q) {... }
```

Comment: More a comment than an answer, but it will probably solve the problem :-)